# Process structure of angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am cakephp Programmer, Now i want to learn Angularjs. Can anyone describe me how to compile processing is going and please also suggest me what are the basic functions or other (like Angular seed, bower etc) I should learn.

Comment: Angular has an extensive documentation. Why don't you read it, and then come back with a more specific question? We won't explain angular and bower here. That is much too broad.

Comment: I want advice who already working in Angularjs.

Comment: Asking for recommentations on what you should learn is also off-topic here.

Comment: Which is related to Angularjs, if is there? like for coding or testing of Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good intro course which is free:
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js